# How to pass a nested model value in @Html.Partial

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have a model as order inside it I have a another object which I am trying to use in @Html.Partial
Code snippet

```
 public class Order{
   public string Id{set;get;}
   public Address BillingAdress{set;get;}
   public Address ShippingAddress{set;get;}
 }

 public class Address{
   public int Id{set;get;}
   public string Address{set;get;}
 }
```

IN VIEW

```
  @model Order
  OrderId: 
  @Html.TextBoxFor(x=>Model.Id)

  ShippingAdress: 
  @Html.Partial("Adress", Model.ShippingAdress)

  BillingAddress:
  @Html.Partial("Adress", Model.BillingAdress)
```

this is not working .
but when I am passing Model instead of Model.ShippingAdress and Model.BillingAdress, TryUpdateModel(Order) is working in controller action can any one tell me why?? 
I have searched in net but not got any concreete solution  so please help me?

Answer (score 1):

The reason for that is because the Partial is not respecting the naming convention for the input fields. Use an editor template instead:

```
@model Order
OrderId: 
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Id)

ShippingAdress: 
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.ShippingAdress)

BillingAddress:
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.BillingAdress)
```

Now move your `Adress.cshtml` to `~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/Address.cshtml`. The name and location of the template is important. It should be located in `~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates` and named the same way as the model type (`Address.cshtml`):

```
@model Address
...
```